# Cannot able to align Autocomplete view

Tags: react-native

```
 <View style={{
           flex: 1,
        paddingTop:100
         }}>


   <Text>asfhjdshfdsbfbusdufn</Text>
   <GooglePlacesAutocomplete
      placeholder='Search'
      minLength={2}
      // minimum length of text to search
      autoFocus={false}
      returnKeyType={'search'} // Can be left out for default return key https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/textinput.html#returnkeytype
      keyboardAppearance={'light'} // Can be left out for default keyboardAppearance https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/textinput.html#keyboardappearance
      listViewDisplayed='auto'    // true/false/undefined
      fetchDetails={true}
      renderDescription={row => row.description} // custom description render
      onPress={(data, details = null) => { // 'details' is provided when fetchDetails = true
        console.log(data, details);
      }}

      getDefaultValue={() => ''}

      query={{
        // available options: https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/autocomplete
        key: 'AIzaSyAPCorWKWM29Dok3YxgfEGMyZB-Tt6SNO4',
        language: 'en', // language of the results
        types: '(cities)' // default: 'geocode'
      }}

      styles={{
        textInputContainer: {
          width: '100%'
        },

        description: {
          fontWeight: 'bold'
        },
        predefinedPlacesDescription: {
          color: '#1faadb'
        }
      }}

      currentLocation={true} // Will add a 'Current location' button at the top of the predefined places list
      currentLocationLabel="Current location"
      nearbyPlacesAPI='GooglePlacesSearch' // Which API to use: GoogleReverseGeocoding or GooglePlacesSearch
      GoogleReverseGeocodingQuery={{
        // available options for GoogleReverseGeocoding API : https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/intro
      }}
      GooglePlacesSearchQuery={{
        // available options for GooglePlacesSearch API : https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/search
        rankby: 'distance',
        type: 'cafe'
      }}

      GooglePlacesDetailsQuery={{
        // available options for GooglePlacesDetails API : https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/details
        fields: 'formatted_address',
      }}

      filterReverseGeocodingByTypes={['locality', 'administrative_area_level_3']} // filter the reverse geocoding results by types - ['locality', 'administrative_area_level_3'] if you want to display only cities
      predefinedPlaces={[homePlace, workPlace]}

      debounce={200} // debounce the requests in ms. Set to 0 to remove debounce. By default 0ms.
    //  renderLeftButton={()  => <Image source={require('path/custom/left-icon')} />}
      renderRightButton={() => <Text>Custom text after the input</Text>}
    />
       </View>

   </MapView>
```

[the image link](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1PPpidHMwWSgYOoFgGV2NyD3vGTCF9S1L)

I am trying to add google autocomplete view to my react native app, I struck while I am trying to align that component it stays on the top and tried padding-top to the container view but it doesn't work ,but the text component is work just fine with alignment whereas the auto complete doesn't obey my behaviour

Answer (score 0):

You can use SafeAreaView. Official document is [here](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/safeareaview)

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to change the style to absolute?

eg:

```
styles={{
        ...
        container: {
           position: 'absolute',
           top: 100,
           left: 10,
           right: 10,
           width: Dimensions.get('window').width - 20,
           height: 50
        }
        ...
      }}
```